# How do i make a count that counts the number of page-views?

Tags: php

I want to count the total number of pages that have been visited by a user. The problem is in my code when a user visits the page the counter increases by 1, which is okay, but when the user refreshes the page many times the counter keeps increasing. I want to increase the counter on first visit of a user, but not when they refresh the page. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: user cookies as identifier

Comment: You should record user ip and datetime, on visit check if it already visited the page today, if not increase counting. You can also restrict the interval to half hour for example and you can truncate that table every day so that it doesn't fill too much space

Comment: You can do a few things to prevent that: A) use a cookie/session B) check user IP, useragent

Comment: Is the question "How many times has a page been visited?" or "How many pages has a particular user visited?"

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use some js tracker like [Google Analytics.](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

If you do not want to track page refresh, you can use [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to store timestamp of last time the increment happened, so you do not increment till it expires.

Comment: what should be the session time for a particular user?

Comment: Well you can store cookie for a session period and increment each time cookie is not set (every time user closes browser and goes to your page). Or you can store cookie till the day end, so you will track kind of unique visitors per 24 hours.

Comment: Its still NOT worth to implement with PHP, better use js tracker. It already takes care about refreshes and so on, it will give you much much more info, than you'd collect yourself.

Comment: @mr.Pavlikov That's assuming that this tracking is for a site exposed to the web through a fully qualified domain name - this could alternatively be for a completely internal system. We don't have enough information to say otherwise because the OP's question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['visited']))
{
    $_SESSION['visited'] = 1;
    //increase the page view counter...
}
```

This, however, won't work if user has disabled cookies, since no cookie support makes browser unable to keep session ID (which is necessary for sessions to work). Thus refreshing in browser w/o cookies will still yield too many clicks.

To deal with these cases, you can remember IPs (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) and check if given IP has visited your page. Note that this solution is still vulnerable -- "sophisticated" attacks that rely on using proxy servers will still be able to count too many clicks.

The best option is to use external tracking system like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a session, a very simple example would be:

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter = 0;

if(! isset($_SESSION['visited'])):
        $counter +=1;
        $_SESSION['visited'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
endif;
echo $_SESSION['counter'];
?>
```

Comment: whats that $_SESSION['visited']?

Comment: $_SESSION['visited'] is an uninitialized session, the value is null on first visit. Once the user visit's for the first time it always results to TRUE, then values are set inside the if statement so that whenever the page is reloaded, the if statement will result to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You may use cookies for this. On visit check if cookie is set, if not than set cookie for the page (cookie lifetime may vary depending on what you want), update counter only if cookie is not set.
If you need counter to be complex - than it is better to use something like Google Analytics.